# MySQL LEFT JOIN query shows same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to make it so that this query below counts rows from another table that have the username, then deaths that have killer. There is 1 row per username in the stats table, but multiple rows with in the pvp table with the username. The deaths column is the same amount as the kills column for some reason, does anyone know why? Here is my query.  Here is a sql fiddle I think I got it right idk how to use sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b793b/1

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,   
    COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
    ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) as kd
FROM
    stats as st
    LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer=st.username
WHERE
    st.username="Username";
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data and the expected results to your question, and also make a sqlfiddle. I can't figure out what you're trying to count, since you haven't shown your schema clearly.

Comment: Please post your table structures.  It sounds like you probably need _two_ joins against the same table, one for kills and one for deaths.

Comment: Yea I do but I dont know how to do so.

Comment: why would you use an alias that's longer than the real table name?!?

Comment: What is the expected result of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT st.*,
       SUM(pvp.killer = st.username) AS kills,
       SUM(pvp.username = st.username) as deaths
FROM stats AS st
LEFT JOIN pvp ON pvp.username = st.username OR pvp.killer = st.username
WHERE st.username = "Username"
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b793b/4)

To do it for everyone, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT st.*,
       SUM(pvp.killer = st.username) AS kills,
       SUM(pvp.username = st.username) as deaths
FROM stats AS st
LEFT JOIN pvp ON pvp.username = st.username OR pvp.killer = st.username
GROUP BY st.username
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b793b/5)

Comment: Thanks, By any chance do you know how to do this same thing, but it will show all users and there pvp/deaths stats instead of searching for 1?

Comment: Added that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(foo)` and `COUNT(bar)` both count the number of rows in the resultset, you might as well say `COUNT(*)` in both cases.

You need to `COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY killer` to get the number of killers, for example. Not sure what the table structure is to give you a full answer.

Comment: Probably best to wait until he posts more details before trying to post an answer.

Comment: `COUNT(foo)` and `COUNT(*)` would be different if `foo` has `NULL` values.