# MySQL Left Join query issue with same values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to make it so that this query below counts rows from another table that have the username, then deaths that have killer. There is 1 row per username in the stats table, but multiple rows with in the pvp table with the username. The deaths column is the same amount as the kills column for some reason, does anyone know why? Here is my query and here is a sql fiddle I think I got it right idk how to use sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b793b/1

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,   
    COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
    ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) as kd
FROM
    stats as st
    LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer=st.username
WHERE
    st.username="Username";
```

Comment: "pvp as pvptable" is not necessary. Aliases are supposed to be shorter... like "user AS U" for example

Comment: Then reply with a fixed solution?

Comment: It's not a solution, it's just a comment. Hence the ..... comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL LEFT JOIN query shows same value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198444/mysql-left-join-query-shows-same-value)

Comment: is the name of ur table name "stats' ?

Comment: count is aggregate group by is required

Answer (score 0):

You are counting 2 columns of the same table. Of course you are going to have the same `COUNT`. Try using `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression, `count(pvtable.killer)` is counting the number of rows that have a non-NULL value for `pvtable.killer` in the result set.  Presumably, the value is never `NULL` for either `killer` or `username`, so they return the same value.

Perhaps you want to count distinct values:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(distinct pvptable.killer) as kills,   
    COUNT(distinct pvptable.username) as deaths,
    ROUND(COUNT(distinct pvptable.killer) / COUNT(distinct pvptable.username), 2) as kd
FROM
    stats as st
    LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer=st.username
WHERE
    st.username="Username";
```

I want to add that answering your questions is unusually difficult.  You should really provide sample data and desired results, along with the queries that you try.  Experience has shown that desired results do a very good job of effectively communicating a problem.